# iPhone is there a way to set the type of animation when going from one view to another?

Tags: iphone

I'm using presentModalViewController to go from view controller to view controller. Right now the animations are up and down when it goes from one view to another.  Can I change it to right and left? I did not see any settings for this in the method presentModalViewController
Ted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this before presenting the modal vc:

```
[sampleViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
// or..
// [sampleViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
// or..
// [sampleViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];
```

See the `modalTransitionStyle` Property of a [UIViewController - Here are the Reference docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

---

You can make convenience methods for all styles like so (from [Modal View Controller Example](http://timneill.net/2010/09/modal-view-controller-example-part-1/)):

```
- (IBAction)showDefault:(id)sender {
    SampleViewController *sampleView = [[[SampleViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self presentModalViewController:sampleView animated:YES];
}
 
- (IBAction)showFlip:(id)sender {
    SampleViewController *sampleView = [[[SampleViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [sampleView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [self presentModalViewController:sampleView animated:YES];
}
 

- (IBAction)showDissolve:(id)sender {
    SampleViewController *sampleView = [[[SampleViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [sampleView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [self presentModalViewController:sampleView animated:YES];
}
 
- (IBAction)showCurl:(id)sender {
    SampleViewController *sampleView = [[[SampleViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [sampleView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];
    [self presentModalViewController:sampleView animated:YES];
}
```